# Is there a function in Python which generates all the strings of length n over a given alphabet?

Tags: python, algorithm, string

I need a function `generateAllStrings(n, alphabet)` to do something like this:

```
generateAllStrings(4, ['a','b'])
>>> ["aaaa", "aaab", "aaba", "aabb", "abaa", .... , "bbba", "bbbb"]
```

In other words, `generateAllStrings(n, alphabet)` should return all the possible strings of length n over the chars in the list alphabet.

Is there such a function in itertools or something?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

```
>>> [''.join(i) for i in itertools.product("ab",repeat=4)]
['aaaa', 'aaab', 'aaba', 'aabb', 'abaa', 'abab', 'abba', 'abbb', 'baaa', 'baab', 'baba', 'babb', 'bbaa', 'bbab', 'bbba', 'bbbb']
```

Comment: I like this much better than my answer =)

Comment: Beautiful: instant +1. A slight addition: instead of brackets for list comprehension, using parenthesis will return an interable instead of a full-fledged pregenerated list.

Comment: +1 for solution, and +1 to Santiago for the iterable remark --> laziness is beautiful.